# boost tree query point intersection

Tags: c++, boost, tree, boost-geometry

I am trying to implement boost trees in a c++ code. Currently I'm doing the following: given a vector of bounding boxes v_bboxes, I build a tree out of it.

```
  LinearPointRtree built_tree(v_bboxes.begin(), v_bboxes.end());
```

Then, given a point, I'd like to know in which of the bounding boxes from v_bboxes the point lies (it might be one or more). Currently I'm making the following query:

```
built_tree.query(bgi::intersects(point), std::back_inserter(result));
```

The result is a vector containing the bounding boxes which contain the point, while I'm interested in indexes referring to the original vector v_bboxes.

I could compare "result" with the original vector and find which bounding boxes were returned, but this would be inefficient and I believe there is a better way of doing this directly with boost, I just cannot find anything in the documentation.

Currently what I am also trying to do is to build a tree starting from a vector of tuples (bounding boxes, index), but it is throwing a very long and bad looking compilation error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘boost::geometry::index::detail::varray >,
>   17>::push_back(std::tuple >, unsigned int>&)’

Does someone know what I should change or has suggestions?

Comment: Put the code where rtree object is created. What is the first template parameter of `rtree` object - `pair<bbox,integer-type>` How do you insert elements into rtree ? Show code, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a better idea is presented, the thing I was trying is correct (the problem was I didn't define the tree properly). So, define the tree

```
template<int spacedim, int leaf_number>
using LinearPointRtree = bgi::rtree<std::tuple<bgBox<spacedim>,unsigned int>, bgi::linear<leaf_number>>;
```

Now create the object:

```
std::vector< std::tuple<bgBox<spacedim>, unsigned int> > boxes_and_indices;
```

Where for each entry there's a bounding box and the desired index. Finally simply build the tree (as boost handles automatically pairs and tuples):

```
LinearPointRtree<spacedim,leaf_number> rstar_tree(flat_global_bboxes.begin(), flat_global_bboxes.end());
```

Then, when querying, you can use the second entry to get the index.

The idea came to me just after posting the question here...anyway, maybe it will help someone else...

Thanks everyone!